# writing a simple Angular Service

Tags: angularjs

OK, I've built services before but obviously I don't actually know what makes them tick, since I can't seem to debug this ultra-simple service call:

app.js:

```
var gridApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);
gridApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', 
    function($scope, dataService) {

        $scope.message = 'I am Angular and I am working.';

        var init = function(){
            console.log(dataService.foo);
            console.log(dataService.getData());
        };

        init();

}]);
```

dataService.js:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('gridApp')
    .service('dataService', dataService)

dataService.$inject = [];

function dataService() {

    console.log("I am the dataService and I am loaded");

    var foo = 1;

    function getData () {
        return 2;
    }

}
})();
```

I see this on-screen: **I am Angular and I am working.** so Angular is loading.

I see this in console: **I am the dataService and I am loaded** so the dataService is actually being loaded.

But then the console.log is:

**undefined** (line 8)

**TypeError: dataService.getData is not a function** (line 9)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers are correct in that your `$http` injection was wrong, but you are also not attaching your service functions to the service:

```
function dataService() {
  var dataService = this;  //get a reference to the service

  //attach your functions and variables to the service reference
  dataService.foo = 1;
  dataService.getData = function() {
    return 2;
  };
}
```

An Angular service is very simply an object class. It is also a singleton, meaning it's instantiated only once per run of your app. When the service is instantiated it is very much akin to calling the `new` operator on your `dataService` "class":

```
var $dataService = new dataService();
```

So, when you inject `dataService` into your controller, you are actually getting an instance, `$dataService`, of your `dataService` "class".

See this blog entry for further reading: https://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider-5f426cfe6b8c#.sneoo52nk

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. I don't quite understand it though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the 2nd parameter `$http` in the function. The named parameters and the actual parameters in function need to be the same, same order and same number. What happened before is that `dataService` was being assigned an `$http` instance and the actual dataService was not injected at all because there was no 3rd parameter to inject it into.

```
var gridApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);
gridApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', 
    function($scope, $http, dataService) {
// ----was missing-----^

        $scope.message = 'I am Angular and I am working.';

        var init = function(){
            console.log(dataService.foo);
            console.log(dataService.getData());
        };

        init();

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. $http was missing, but the real problem was in the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

We have missed the second param '$http' in function. Just add the '$http' param, it should work fine

```
var gridApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);
gridApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', 
    function($scope,$http, dataService) {

        $scope.message = 'I am Angular and I am working.';

        var init = function(){
            console.log(dataService.foo);
            console.log(dataService.getData());
        };

        init();

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been taught to set up services:

```
function dataService() {
    var dataService = {};
    var _foo = 1;
    var _getData = function () { return 2; }

    dataService.foo = _foo;
    dataService.getData = _getData;

    return dataService;
}
```

I believe this  facilitates public/private methods/vars.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is the full code accessing my service:

app.js:

```
var gridApp = angular.module('gridApp', []);

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
gridApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService) {

    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Angular is working';

    var init = function(){
        getPackageData();
    };

    var getPackageData = function (){
        return dataService.getData().then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    };

    init();

}]);
```

dataService.js:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('gridApp')
    .service('dataService', dataService)

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {

    var dataService = {};

    var _getData = function () {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'data/packages.json'
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        },
            function errorCallback(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }

    dataService.getData = _getData;

    return dataService;
}
})();
```